# How to capture current location (on canvas) of an MDIWindow, after it has been moved?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mdi, silverlightcontrols

I have a Silverlight 4 app that has a canvas with five MDIWindows on it. The **Canvas.Left** and **Canvas.Top** properties are set in XAML. These five MDIWindows can be moved around with the mouse. I am trying to use **IsolatedStorageSettings** to save their current location, invoked from a button event. However, when I call **MDIWhatever.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)** I always get the initial value of **Canvas.Left** as set in XAML, and what I want is the *current* location. I've tried calling **InvalidateArrange()** and **UpdateLayout()** on both the **MDIWindow** and **LayoutRoot** (the canvas).

```
Private Sub btnSaveLayout_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSaveLayout.Click

    MDIWhatever.InvalidateArrange()
    MDIWhatever.UpdateLayout()
    LayoutRoot.InvalidateArrange()
    LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout()

    _settings.Clear()
    _settings.Add("MDILeft", MDIWhatever.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty))
    _settings.Add("MDITop", MDIWhatever.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty))
    _settings.Save()

End Sub
```

This ought to be easy, what am I missing?

EDIT: This is a third-party control, from off of Codeplex. I assumed it was part of Silverlight because of the **System.Windows.Controls** namespace. I did not expect a third-party control to use this namespace instead of having its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than get this one to work, I found another control that supports a Position property (that returns a Point object of the current position). FloatingWindowControl at http://jevgenijpankov.heliocode.com/articles/FloatingWindow.aspx